# Is there a way to update Jetpack Navigation Graph for a Fragment that can be accessible by any Fragment in the Graph?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Given I have a Jetpack Navigation Graph as below, where by

BlankFragment1 -> BlankFragment2 -> BlankFragment3 -> BlankFragment4 -> BlankFragment5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment1">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment1"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment1"
        android:label="@string/label_blank1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank1" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_blankFragment1_to_blankFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/blankFragment2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment2"
        android:label="@string/label_blank2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank2" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_blankFragment2_to_blankFragment3"
            app:destination="@id/blankFragment3" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment3"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment3"
        android:label="@string/label_blank3"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank3" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_blankFragment3_to_blankFragment4"
            app:destination="@id/blankFragment4" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment4"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment4"
        android:label="@string/label_blank4"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank4" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_blankFragment4_to_blankFragment5"
            app:destination="@id/blankFragment5" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment5"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment5"
        android:label="@string/label_blank5"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank5" />

</navigation>
```

If I have another Fragment, named FragmentSomething, that can be open by and of the FragmentBlank1 to FragentBlank5

Is there a way to update the NavGraph above for my FragmentSomething, without the need to add actions for all 5 of them?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's something called the global action

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action

We just need to add this

```
    <action android:id="@+id/action_global_somethingFragment"
          app:destination="@id/somethingFragment"/>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/somethingFragment"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.SomethingFragment"
        android:label="@string/label_something"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_something" />
```

Or we can navigate the code directly to `somethingFragment` using

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.somethingFragment)
```